How to send LinkedIn connection request using LinkedIn API
I am using the LinkedIn API for an internal application but am encountering issues obtaining access tokens with the r_compliance and w_compliance permissions.
How can I resolve this and gain access to these permissions? My main goal is to use the invitation and messaging endpoints.
I have tried both two-legged and three-legged OAuth, but I continue to receive the following error when using two-legged OAuth:
{
   "error": "access_denied",
   "error_description": "This application is not allowed to create application tokens"
}


Do you use the authorization_code correctly? sharing some code would be helpful
